# Will a mowed down tree sapling grow back?

Tags: trees

My granddaughter got a tree sapling from school for Earth day and I planted it in my backyard. I forgot it was there and mowed it down. It was in a little bit of a hole from there not being enough dirt to cover it completely, so there's still a branch or two still on the trunk. She is devastated.

Will it grow back or is there a way to grow it back?

Comment: What species of tree?

Comment: PawPaws regrow. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asimina_triloba

Answer (score 5):

It is difficult to know, some trees could change shape and going shrub-like, some will just continue, maybe with two tops, and some will not growth anymore.

All it depends on the species, and so about the ability to create new buds near cuttings or from roots, to make some secondary bods the new "main one" (but so often with two heads), or just not creating new buds. And then it depends on apical dominance: if new buds could create new branch which could become trunk (of just a disordered shrub).

Conifers are particularly difficult (and monocots e.g. palms, but they are not really trees): not many plan B and we like when they growth very regularly.

As you see, plants often have plan B, so possibly it will not die, but maybe you will never have a good shaped tree.

In any case: I always recommend to put a stick near every sapling, for mowers, for waling people, for snow/wind and for animals.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience if a sapling comes up off of an existing root with a large tree next to it it will come back, unless it's covered.

If there's a tree branch, or two still left on the tree, it should bounce back, but if it doesn't put some green on it to start regrowing you can always plant a better tree with her for mother's day as it's just around the corner, and tell her it will produce some tasty fruit for her for years to come :D